# When checking if value is null i get: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I monitor user's keyboard in order to return suggestions from an API. I use a reactive form and i check the input values with this method:

```
  private getQuery() {
    return this.playerForm.get('playerInput').valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(200));
  }
```

With this implementation I send constantly the current input queries to the backend and the backend returns the results. I used switchMap for this logic.

```
  private getAutoSuggestions() {
    this.subs.sink = this.getQuery().pipe(
      switchMap(query => {
        if (query !== null) { 
          return this.store.getPlayers(query);
        }
      })
    ).subscribe((backendList: Player[]) => {
      this.playersList = backendList;
    });
  }
```

This logic works fine, but i needed to make an extra check because it sends some null values, suppose because of the async calls of RxJS. When i added the (if query !== null) i got the error:

**TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable. at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:40)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `switchMap()` would always expect an Observable return, you aren't returning anything when `query` is null. That's why the error.

If you get `null` then you need to handle it. Maybe by either returning the same `playerList` or an empty list, depends on your requirement.

```
private getAutoSuggestions() {
    this.subs.sink = this.getQuery().pipe(
    switchMap(query => {
        if (query !== null) { 
            return this.store.getPlayers(query);
        } else {
            return of([...this.playersList]) // or return of([]) 
        }
    })
    ).subscribe((backendList: Player[]) => {
        this.playersList = backendList;
    });
}
```